# NSSortDescriptor with relationship

Tags: ios, xcode, nsfetchrequest, nssortdescriptor

Got 3 Entities in my CoreData Models

Formations with a sections relationship to a Sections entity and chapters relationship with a Chapters entity.

So A Formation contains 1 or n sections containing 1 or n chapters

In my section Entity, there is a `sortNB` attribute (a kind of `id`), so I would like to sort my sections in my request.

I tried to do :

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Formations" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];
[request setEntity:entity];


NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sections.sortNB" ascending:YES];
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"sections", nil]];
[request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];


NSArray *forms = [[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil]mutableCopy];
```

But got an error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'to-many key not allowed here'
```

How can I proceed ?

I would like to insert same kind of number in my Chapters entity to sort it too, but first, let's resolve it for Sections :p

Thanks

Comment: so what exactly is your `sortNB`, and on which line are you getting the error? You may be comparing a collection of stuff to a single stuff.

Comment: Got the error when I execute my request so at the last line. sortNB is string type, but I can convert it to a NSNumber if needed. Each formation got 1 or n Sections with 1 or n Chapters

Comment: You are fetching `Formations` objects, and these cannot be sorted by `sections.sortNB`, because each formation is related to multiple sections.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so I sort my objects not in my request but after using

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"sortNB" ascending:YES]];

NSArray *sortedRecipes = [[[formation sections] allObjects] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

And it works.

Thanks for your help.